# Grails & JMS Spring Integration: 'selector-expression' in recipient-list-router not working

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin, spring-integration, spring-jms

Following is the code which is not working:
SampleGrailsPlugin.groovy

```
def doWithSpring = {
 integration{
  'recipient-list-router'(id:'listenerRouter','input-channel':'inChannel')
  {
   recipient('selector-expression':"false",'channel':'outChannel')
  }
 }
}
```

What ever value I give in 'selector-expression', message is getting routed to 'outChannel'. Can somebody help?

Thank you

Keerthi

Comment: I am using Grails 1.3.4 and using org.springframework.integration-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar -- could this be the problem? Do I have to use Spring integration 2.0 release for this?